# Is vscode-python extension for VSCode is a Language Service or just an extension only?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, language-server-protocol

I want to write an extension for VSCode that reuse refactor/rename function of [vscode-python](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python) extension. So that, when the user executes my command, my extension will do rename on a variable of .py file. I don't know if `vscode-python` is just an extension only or it's implementing Language Server Protocol LSP. And how I call the rename/refactor function of `vscode-python`. Can you give me some hints? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that the Python extension is implementing the VSCode API directly for features such as rename, rather than using the LSP abstraction layer. See for instance its `renameProvider.ts`, which implements `vscode.RenameProvider`:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/blob/c976b6c98e34e041b7ee826ec22f9820ba90f8ac/src/client/providers/renameProvider.ts

I don't think how it's implemented really matters to you as a caller though - It seems like you're in luck, the ability to programatically trigger a rename was added just recently and will be released soon as part of VSCode 1.25.0 / the June release:

[API to programmatically begin rename (#50856)](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/50856)

It's also part of the [release notes for the upcoming version](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/5a73eac2c722b05530cc51d361d46a8b6feb5a0c/release-notes/v1_25.md#rename-command), which give the following usage example:

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand(
  'editor.action.rename',
  [vscode.Uri.file('/my/file.abc'), new vscode.Position(14, 7)]
)
```